# Recovering Funds Sent on the Wrong Network. How do I drain the account after creating the safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

A while back, a client had accidentally sent some USDT on the ETH network instead of on the BNB network to our safe.

I've just followed the tutorial here by Mikhail: https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741

Here's the link to the created safe & address:
https://app.safe.global/balances?safe=eth:0xB410ad92D1c8158cF34DcABe969C5Ed84C604678
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xB410ad92D1c8158cF34DcABe969C5Ed84C604678

You can see there's around $513 in USDT stuck there.

I managed to create the safe on Gnosis, but the funds didn't show up. The USDT Token isn't visible on the safe. Only ETH is. I contacted support through the chat and Inah kindly replied: "So this is normal that you won't be able to see your assets after replaying the safe. Mainnet and L2/Sidechains Safes use a slightly different contract. So they are incompatible with our UI/backend out of the box. You'll need to interact with the replayed safe through Safe CLI https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli. If it loads on the web app, you can also interact using the Transaction Builder Safe app."

I've tried to access the balance through safe-cli but it still shows up as zero. I'm not sure where to go from here. The safe is created on Gnosis, the balance is zero there. Through safe-cli, the balance still shows up as zero.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use
**[transaction-builder](https://app.safe.global/apps/open?safe=eth:0xB410ad92D1c8158cF34DcABe969C5Ed84C604678&appUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.gnosis-safe.io%2Ftx-builder)**

1. Go to the Gnosis app and open the Safe you created. Click
   on the "Apps". Look for the **Transaction Builder** app and open it
2. In the "Contract Interaction" section, enter the USDT contract address and the ABI of the USDT
   contract (It should be auto-filled after you pasted the address). If not, you can find the ABI on Etherscan.
3. Choose the `transfer`
   function and enter your `address` (receiver) and the amount of USDT you want to transfer.
4. Click `Submit Transaction`, and confirm and execute the transaction.

If you can afford it, I recommend you test with a small amount first.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I've gotten what I think is the USDT contract address. What should I select for contract method selector?

Comment: `transfer` function

Comment: Should "To address" stay the same as the contract address? Then the field that says _to (address) is my address, and also is _Value (uint256) the amount in ETH or USDT?

Comment: Tried testing but I ended up just losing $2 in gas fees unfortunately. I think i'm doing something wrong. I entered "5" as the amount, kept both "to" fields the same and executed the transaction, nothing ended up happening.

Comment: can you share the transaction

Comment: It worked this time! Duuuuuuude, you're a life saver. I appreciate you bro. All worked the second time. Thank you my friend!

Comment: Great to hear that it's working!  what might have caused the issue the first time?

Comment: I shouldn't have made both "to" fields the same receiver address. The first "to" field was meant to be the same as the contract address, then the second to field was meant to be the receiver address.